# cordova ionic barcode scanner error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

i am getting same error

barcodescanner.js:130 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

ionic.bundle.js:20306 ReferenceError: cordova is not defined

Cordova CLI: 5.0.0
Gulp version: CLI version 3.8.11
Gulp local: Local version 3.8.11
Ionic Version: 1.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.4.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.0.19
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 3.1.1 
OS: Mac OS X Mavericks
Node Version: v0.12.2
Xcode version: Xcode 6.1.1 Build version 6A2008a

my index.html

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>


<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova-mocks.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/barcodescanner.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

------app.js contains-----------------

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngCordova'])
```

------controllers.js contains-------------------

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngCordova'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $stateParams, $http, $cordovaBarcodeScanner) {

.......

$scope.scanBarcode = function() {
var scanner = cordova.plugins.BarcodeScanner;
if (scanner == undefined) {
scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");
}

scanner.scan()     
        .then(function (imageData) {     
                alert(imageData.text);
                console.log(imageData.format);     
                // Success! Barcode data is here     
             }, function (err) {     
                 console.log(err);     
                 // An error occurred     
             });     
    };
```

can anybody help me out ?

Comment: Have you tested on a real device?

Comment: I was testing on emulator.i have not tested it on real one yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the iOS Simulator you can't test this plugin because the simulator does not support the camera. So you need to use a real device to test you app.

Check the documentation:
[Testing and Debugging in iOS Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW1)

**UPDATE**

Your code seems to have some errors. 
Try this example, I haven't tested but should works:

Controller

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngCordova'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $stateParams, $http, $cordovaBarcodeScanner) {

  $scope.scanBarcode = function(){
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(barcodeData) {
      // Success! Barcode data is here
      alert('barcode scanned:' +  barcodeData.text);
    }, function(error) {
      alert('Error')
      console.log(error);
      // An error occurred
    });      
  };

});
```

HTML:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-click="scanBarcode()">
      Scan Barcode
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I just tested it on my iphone 5S, it did not work..Can i debug the code while running on iphone to see what the errors are...

Comment: wow..it works now..appreciate your help. I have one question. my hybrid ios app talks to java library which inturn gets data from mongoDB or some other REST service.. What is the best cloud service to host my java app and db.